# Jupyter no active kernels, terminals or notebooks

Tags: jupyter

I am completely new to Jupyter.  I've installed in Linux Mint 15 (Ubuntu derivative) on both python2 and python3 (trying different stuff) using (sudo pip3 install jupyter; sudo pip3 install turbinado).  It runs and serves the tree page a :8888 and I can click on a file and open it in a browser window called .../edit/ploy.py.  I can go to the "running" tab and it says "terminals unavailable", "there are not notebooks running".

Over in the "edit" window, there was no way to run the program.  I only have "file edit view language... Python" in the header.  By looking at google images I think that there should be a lot more buttons...  This is how it starts:

$ jupyter notebook
[I 11:25:23.268 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /me/bitcoin/1tx
[I 11:25:23.268 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 11:25:23.268 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 11:25:23.268 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

Comment: you may want to include a screenshot.

Comment: I gave up and ran scipy and pygal (graphing library) instead.  Took me 5 minutes to get up and running.

Comment: In the tree page (and with a current notebook version), there should be a "New" button in the upper right corner, which you can use to open new notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You should click to add a new *Notebook* rather than a normal python file.